# DLL appsettings returns null (looking at web.config instead of DLLs app.config)

Tags: asp.net, web-config, app-config

We have a DLL and it has its own app settings. Now if I use the dll in the ASP .Net website, `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]` is looking at website's web.config instead of DLL's App.config.

Is it possible to get the config settings in the DLL's app.config rather than website's web.config?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Raja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DLL cannot have its own configuration.

A library executes in the context of an application (web or otherwise) - the configuration is that of this application.

Comment: That is what I thought too but just wanted to confirm :-). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the code below to get my dll's config. Hope it helps.

```
_config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
_rootPath = _config.AppSettings.Settings["RootPath"].Value;
```

Comment: This will return the config settings of the executing application. The OP is asking about getting the config settings for a specific DLL.

Comment: yes but i wrote it inside the dll. so it returns dll's config.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I expect it is returning the config of the _application_ the DLL runs under.

Comment: Yes, my application doesn't even have a config file.